# Python program running with using init.d don't write data

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I wrote Python script which measuring SPL and I want save score in log file and used function open() and write(). Everything work well when I run script in shell. When I add may script to init.d, my script don't write data in file only create file.

MAIN SCRIPT F.py is wrote in Python 2.7

```
card = 'default'
roz_data = 128
array_float = numpy.dtype(float)
stream = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, card)
stream.setchannels(1)
stream.setrate(48000)
stream.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
stream.setperiodsize(roz_data)
def listen():
    print("Listening")
    glob_leq = 0 # suma kwadratow z tablicy (375 po 128 przy probkowaniu 48000)
    liczba_ramek = 0
    b, a = A_weighting(48000)
    index_ramek = 0
    while True:
            try:
                    arch = open("/home/pi/A/mikrofon.txt","a")
                    l, data = stream.read()
            except IOError, e:
                    error_count += 1
                    print(" (%d) Error recording: %s" % (error_count, e))
            else:
                    if l==roz_data:
                            decoded_block = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype='int16' )
                    else:
                            continue
                    decoded_block = lfilter(b , a, decoded_block)
                    maks = 32768
                    array_float = numpy.divide(decoded_block ,float( maks))
                    array_float = array_float**2
                    sum_array = numpy.sum(array_float, dtype=float)
                    glob_leq = glob_leq + sum_array
                    liczba_ramek += 1
                    index_ramek += 1
                    if index_ramek == 3750:
                       index_ramek=0
                       cis_chwil = numpy.divide(glob_leq, liczba_ramek * roz_data)
                       leq =10*numpy.log10(numpy.divide(cis_chwil, hPa))
                       dB = str(format(leq,'.2f'))
                       czas = str(time.time())
                       arch.writelines(czas + ' ' + dB + '\n')
                       glob_leq=0
                       liczba_ramek=0

listen()
```

And init script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/mic

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Skrypt
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: Skrypt
# Description:       Skrypt
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting mic recoding"
    # run application you want to start
    python /home/pi/A/f.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping skrypt"
    # kill application you want to stop
    killall python
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/mic{start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Maybe close the file before opening it again.

Comment: Perhaps you also need to create the appropriate symlinks in `/etc/rc*.d` via `chkconfig` or whatever your specific distro uses?

Comment: It is Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #2 SMP armv7l

Comment: Side note: The ``killall python`` might kill a lot more than what you intended...

Answer (score 0):

Creating a proper daemon (process that runs in the background) is deceptively complicated to get all the details correct. Probably best not to reinvent the wheel and use an existing library to handle the details for you. Such as [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/). You can then configure the daemon to write a PID file, so you can kill the specific process instead of every python process on your system.

Comment: Oki. I try use python-daemon and will write whether bring result.

Comment: I know where is problem. When daemon run with my script he have process state S  that mean it is waiting for something (sleep) probably I must change way writing data but when I run from shell got process state R (run).

Comment: That is not *the* problem you describe above. It is a problem however in that your daemon looks like it uses 100% CPU and never sleeps.

Comment: I am solve this problem. Probably something different between user path and root. Enough use a sudo with switch -s ex. starting command should be look like "sudo -s pi python /home/pi/A/f.py". By the way thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am solve this problem. Probably something different between user path and root not with daemon. Enough use a sudo with switch -s ex. starting command should be look like "sudo -s pi python /home/pi/A/f.py" with starting script in init.d.